# How to fix chmod -R 777 /usr

Tags: permissions, chmod

I know :) I'm an idiot :)

I did `chmod -R 777 /usr`

I was able to run `chmod -R 755/usr` from recovery mode. Now almost all work well. But the Software update and a few other futures still don't work.

Anybody knows default permissions for the content of `/usr`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/626977/restore-permission-default-of-usr-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 1):

Well you used the -R (recursive) flag then your system is screwed , the best solution is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Another way to fix it, is to install the same version of Linux on another machine (or VM) then just copy `/usr` over to the old machine , good luck.